# Kendo - insert event attribute

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I created a generic js DataGrid creator and here's the code:

```
function createGrid(targetDiv, mycolums, source, fnChange) {
  return $(targetDiv).kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
          data: source,
          pageSize: 20
       },
      scrollable: true,
      sortable: true,
      pageable: {
        input: true,
        numeric: false
       },
    columns: mycolums, 
    change: fnChange
});
}
```

to call it:

```
createGrid("#grid1", columns, dataSource, onChange);
```

it's working fine, but I want to somehow modify my create grid functions, since there a times that some grid needs to bound to other event like `edit : fnEdit` and the likes.

> My Question is that, how can I modify the `createGrid` to accept objects instead of specific parameters. let say I want to make it some-thing like:

```
function createGrid(targetDiv, mycolums, source, OtherAttributes) {
  return $(targetDiv).kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
          data: source,
          pageSize: 20
       },
      scrollable: true,
      columns: mycolums, 
      OtherAttributes
   });
```

so that I may call it something like:

```
createGrid("#grid1", columns, dataSource, {change: OnChange, edit: OnEdit});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you propose should work fine. In your function, just check the object properties when setting the grid properties:

```
var otherAttrs = {
  change: onChange,
  dataBound: onDatabound                  
};

createGrid(div, cols, datas, otherAttrs);

function createGrid(targetDiv, mycolums, source, opts) {
    return $(targetDiv).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: source,
            pageSize: 20
         },
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        selectable: "multiple, row",
        pageable: {
          input: true,
          numeric: false
        },
        columns: mycolums, 
        change: opts.change ? opts.change : null,
        dataBound: opts.dataBound ? opts.dataBound : null,
   });
```

}

> Working **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OPaMA)**